# angularjs ajax post fails Json objects with MVC 5 500 Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I have an update button that is tied to my angularjs.

I keep getting 500 error.

When I click on the button, I see that I am posting ID 1 and today "4" but for some reason my MVC though I have a valid controller does not get triggered. Below are some of my controllers I tried.

javascript and angular ..

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="update()"> Update </button>

 function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {
 $scope.update = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Home/EditResult",
                    data: {
                        ID: angular.toJson($scope.today.ID),
                        today: angular.toJson($scope.day)
                    },
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });
            }
```

My controller

```
public JsonResult EditResult(int ID, string today)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return Json("string");
    }




    public JsonResult EditResult(string ID, string today)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return Json("string");
    }


    public JsonResult EditResult(JsonResult data)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return Json("string");
    }
```

I also tried full post, that failed too

```
$scope.update = function() {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'Home/EditResult',
                data: {ID: $scope.today.ID, today: $scope.day},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}

            }).success(function() {
                alert(data);
            });
        };
```

Comment: Check your server log. In that you will find some error logged.

Comment: Should be a backend issue. By the way, why don't you use angular service $http to send this reqeust. I don't think use jquery to send a ajax request in controller is good pratice.

Comment: Or can you post your angular code to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambiguous controller... changed name of other controllers and used only one and was able to post with either of the above ajax or full post.